# Bourbaki style book layout

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, book-design, layout

I am trying to hone my layout skills, and what's better than trying to start by copying the Bourbaki style and then going up from there? Thus, I want to achieve the following chaptering and sectioning style of Bourbaki for the class `book`:

1. The book starts with a [«title page»](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04TPP.png) naming the series name.
2. This is followed by a [«title page»](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlzZK.png) for the current volume.
3. Then there's a [*To the Reader*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyf5d.png) and a terse [*Contents of the Series*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itkQo.png) (without any page break), not beginning on a new page, and mentioning only the chapters of all the volumes.
4. Then comes long *Contents* (the usual "ToC")[[img-first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1cWU.png), [img-last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAN7n.png)] which enlists the chapters in the current volume with the subsection depth.
5. The [chapters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYZky.png) (numbered) contain sections which contain subsections, all numbered. Then at the end of each chapter are the following unnumbered sections, if any (all start on a new page, except for exercises, which are grouped together):

   - [Appendix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCzHD.png) (at most one)
   - [*Exercises*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0VAK.png) which are grouped by the chapter sections including a separate group for those for the appendix; the long *Contentes* should enlist not the *Exercises* but *Exercises for § x* (x being the section number) or *Exercises for the Appendix* as unnumbered sections (not as subsections).
   - [*Historical Note*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbfpV.png) and [*Bibliography*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSzN6.png), with *Bibliography* occurring without any page break. But on the long *Contents*, they appear as separate sections.
6. An unnumbered chapter *Summary of results* which contains the following sections:

   - An unnumbered *Introduction*
   - Numbered sections
   - Unnumbered *Index of notation*
   - Unnumbered *Index of terminology*
   - Unnumbered *Axioms and schemes of the theory of sets*

The pagination is as follows:

1. Footer: Page numbers flushed outward (remember, it's a book, so outward makes sense!) with the Arabic page numbering starting from the long *Contents* and using roman numbers before that.
2. Header:

   - Verso pages should contain in center the chapter title.
   - Recto pages should contain in center the last section that appears on them; and the corresponding section number on flushed right.

---

Now the question is, where do I get started? Can I automate the whole process?

---

Even answers as partial as just mentioning a package that makes only a single aspect in the above, are appreciated!

Comment: If you want to design some layout for a publication, start with those things that affect most others, such as the paper size. Then go on with headers, footers and pagination (I'd assume that this is similar on most pages), and finally design the titles and other more granular stuff. But it is, of course, up to you how you manage this.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Good advice! Do you know some helpful packages that make the process bearable?

Comment: @Atom, just enter into google serach terms like: ctan header etc. That's easier than searching on https://ctan.org/ directly. BTW, some packages may conflict with each other. A good indication is scanning this site for potential trouble.

Comment: If using LaTeX, I would probably use the `memoir` class, and go over the manual to see how to tweak most of the things you seem to want. Then maybe come back with a more specific question if there was still something I was stuck with.

Comment: I don't think that there exists one single package for everything you need. Some document classes might cover a lot of things already, but if you want to use a basic document class such as `article`, you'd need to stitch together the packages that provide the relevant features you need to change. I'd rather make a good plan first: Take the list you wrote down with all the requirements you need and then stepwise think about which packages there are and how you can best make use of them. If you have a good idea of how everything can work together, start with the actual coding.

Comment: @Atom There are very few shortcuts either in math or programming. I would start from the amsclass and modify as little as possible. It has very good documentation, is easy to read and you will be able to get a lot of support if you have queries. Add packages ONLY as you need them. Use the amsclass for a few chapters as a mock-up first to understand the changes you want to make. Write a specification of what you want the class to do and tick them as you go along.